# Spring's PayloadValidatingInterceptor evaluates XML (uncorrect) invalid

Tags: validation, xsd, spring-ws

I'm developing in a Spring project using Sping-WS (2.1).

Using the PayloadValidatingInterceptor the messages we're sending via Spring Mock or soapUI are rated invalid.

We checked the XSD several times and we're sure, the data and the schema are correct.
I implemented two test cases inside our SpringJUnit4ClassRunner using the springframework.xml-validator engine and javax.xml.validation classes to validate the payload outside of the WS against the schema. There they're valid.

Does anybody knows a reason why the validation inside the WS behaves different to the manual validation?

Comment: After some test with different XSD configurations I figured out, the validation in the interceptor has a problem to identify unqualified attributes. Qualified ones are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some problems with the `PayloadValidatingInterceptor` as well. I created a simple alternative, based on what I read [here](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/tag/exception-handling/). Sometimes the interceptor will not work as expected - making it `StringReader`-based instead of `String`-based solved my problems. Perhaps this will help solving your issue as well!

---

To detail the solution given there, you can replace the interceptor with a proxy class like this:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransformerException;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage;

public class PayloadValidatingInterceptorWithSourceFix extends
        PayloadValidatingInterceptor {

    @Override
    protected Source getValidationRequestSource(WebServiceMessage request) {
        return transformSourceToStreamSourceWithStringReader(request
                .getPayloadSource());
    }

    @Override
    protected Source getValidationResponseSource(WebServiceMessage response) {
        return transformSourceToStreamSourceWithStringReader(response
                .getPayloadSource());
    }

    Source transformSourceToStreamSourceWithStringReader(
            Source notValidatableSource) {
        final Source source;
        try {
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                    .newTransformer();

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,
                    "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(notValidatableSource,
                    new StreamResult(writer));

            String transformed = writer.toString();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(transformed);
            source = new StreamSource(reader);

        } catch (TransformerException transformerException) {
            throw new WebServiceTransformerException(
                    "Could not convert the source to a StreamSource with a StringReader",
                    transformerException);
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
<bean id="payloadValidatingInterceptorWithSourceFix"
    class="path.to.your.PayloadValidatingInterceptorWithSourceFix">
    <property name="schema"
        value="file:WebContent/WEB-INF/schemas/account-balance-service.xsd" />
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
    <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day. ;) The implementation descriped in the linked blog works.

Comment: saved my day too, have been hitting my head against this for far too long.